# ¿Cómo actualizar un repositorio bifurcado?

Tags: git, github

> Pregunta original: [How to update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository) [de Lea Hayes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/656172/lea-hayes)

Yo recientemente he bifurcado un proyecto y he aplicado algunas correciones. Luego solicité una petición de extracción.

Unos días más tarde una nueva modificación fue hecha por otro contribuidor. Por lo que mi bifurcación no tenía ese cambio...¿Cómo puedo obtener este cambio en mi bifurcación?

¿Necesito borrar y recrear mi bifurcación cuando tenga más cambios para contribuir? ¿Hay algún botón de actualizar?

Comment: Yo uso Tortoise Git, lo recomiendo.

Answer (score 1):

> Respuesta original: [How to update a GitHub forked repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-to-update-a-github-forked-repository/7244456#7244456) [de Mark Longhair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair)

En el clone local del repositorio bifurcado, puedes añadir el repositorio Github original como “remoto”. (“Remotos” son como apodos de las URLs de repositorios – `origin` es uno de ellos, por ejemplo ) Luego puedes recuperar todas las ramas del repositorio superior, y rebasar tu trabajo para continuar trabajando en la versión superior. En términos de comandos podría ser así:

```
# Añade el remoto, llámalo "upstream":

git remote add upstream https://github.com/usuario/proyecto.git

# Recupera todas las ramas del remoto en ramas remote-tracking
# tales como  upstream/master:

git fetch upstream

# Asegurate de que estas en la rama principal:

git checkout master

# Reescribir tu rama maestra para que tenga cualquier commits tuyos
# que no están ya en upstream/master son dispuestas arriba de
# la otra rama:

git rebase upstream/master
```

Si no quieres reescribir la historia de tu bifurcación maestra, (por ejemplo porque otras personas podrían haberlo clonado) , entonces deberías reemplazar el último comando por `git merge upstream/master`. Sin embargo, hacer más peticiones de extracción tan claras como sea posible, es probablemente mejor que rebasar.

Actualización: Si has rebasado tu bifurcación en `upstream/master` podrías necesitar forzar el empuje en vez de empujar a tu propio repositorio bifurcado in Github. Harías eso con:

```
git push -f origin master
```

Sólo necesitas utilizar `-f` la primera vez que hayas rebasado.

Answer (score 0):

Si has realizado un *fork* de un repositorio en Github. Eso quiere decir que tienes una copia para ti. La puedes borrar la puedes incluso dinamitar y esto no afectaria en lo mas minimo al repositorio original.

Respecto a la actualizacion de un repositorio bifurcado.

Debes hacer lo siguiente.

#### 1) Debes dirigirte al directorio de tu repositorio.

```
 cd /directorio/repositorio/github/
```

#### 2) Busca en Github el repositorio original y obten la *URL*. Y ejecuta el siguiente comando en el directorio de tu repositorio.

```
 git pull https://github.com/PROPIETARIO_ORIGINAL/REPOSITORIO_ORIGINAL.git
```

#### 3) A continuacion tu repositorio, a nivel local, esta actualizado. Asi que no resta mas que subir los cambios nuevos a tu bifurcacion en Github.

```
 git push origin master
```

Despues de seguir estos pasos tu version del respositorio original, se encontrara tambien actualizada con los cambios existentes en el repositorio de Github.